# How to solve $A^{\frac 12} B A^{\frac 12} = C$ for $A$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Suppose that matrices $A,B,C$ are symmetric and positive definite. Then, $A$ has a unique, positive square root, which we call $A^{\frac 12}$. If $$A^{\frac 12} B A^{\frac 12} = C$$ then can we write an expression for $A$ in terms of $B, C$?

Comment: Note that this equation is nonlinear in $A$ (or any function of $A$), so existence of a closed expression for the general solution seems unlikely.

Comment: Let me mention that it is easy to give a solution when $B$ commutes with $C$ (just work in the common eigenbasis), but it's not clear to me whether this is the only solution.

Comment: Good point... in a way, the square root is superfluous. We could ask if $A B A = C$ has a solution for $A$. This is a quadratic equation in $A$... for scalars we have closed form solutions for quadratic equations, but do we have them for matrices?

Comment: Thanks for getting me to look at it this way. This gives a searchable keyword with papers like [this](https://kb.osu.edu/bitstream/handle/1811/22234/V074N5_273.pdf?sequence=1). I believe this paper has the solution, which differs from the proposed ones so far. I will add this solution when I understand it (or I'll happily accept the solution if someone else explains it).

Comment: Another keyword comment for future searches, this is related to the "matrix Riccati equation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: find the solutions of the equation

(*) $XBX=C$ where the unknown $X$ and the given matrices $B,C$ are $n\times n$ symmetric $>0$.

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ (*) has the unique solution

$X=B^{-1/2}S^{1/2}B^{-1/2}$, where $S=B^{1/2}CB^{1/2}$.

$\textbf{Proof}.$ (*) is equivalent to $(XB)^2=CB$, that is,

$(XB)^2=B^{-1/2}SB^{1/2}$, where $S$ is symmetric $>0$.

We put $XB=B^{-1/2}ZB^{1/2}$ where $Z^2=S$.

Then $Z=B^{1/2}XB^{1/2}$ is symmetric $>0$ and $Z=S^{1/2}$.

Finally $X=B^{-1/2}S^{1/2}B^{-1/2}$ as required. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

We have the following quadratic matrix equation in symmetric positive definite matrix $\mathrm X$

$$\mathrm X \mathrm B \mathrm X = \mathrm C$$

Since matrix $\rm B$ is symmetric and positive definite, it has a (symmetric and positive definite) square root. Left- and right-multiplying both sides of the matrix equation by $\mathrm B^{\frac 12}$, we get

$$\mathrm B^{\frac 12} \mathrm X \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \mathrm X \mathrm B^{\frac 12} = \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \mathrm C \mathrm B^{\frac 12}$$

Let $\mathrm Y := \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \mathrm X \mathrm B^{\frac 12}$. Hence, we have the following quadratic matrix equation in $\rm Y$

$$\mathrm Y^2 = \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \mathrm C \mathrm B^{\frac 12}$$

Since matrix $\rm C$ is symmetric and positive definite, the RHS of the matrix equation above is also symmetric and positive definite and, thus, it has a (symmetric and positive definite) square root. Hence, the solution is

$$\mathrm Y = \left( \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \mathrm C \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \right)^{\frac 12}$$

and, thus, the solution of the original quadratic matrix equation is

$$\mathrm X = \color{blue}{\mathrm B^{-\frac 12} \left( \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \mathrm C \mathrm B^{\frac 12} \right)^{\frac 12} \mathrm B^{-\frac 12}}$$

Comment: Why do you think your first equation implies the second one?

Comment: Are you interpreting the first equation as implying that: $A^{1/2} B^{1/2} = C^{1/2}$ and $B^{1/2} A^{1/2}  = C^{1/2}$ (possibly with minus signs)? This can only be true if $B^{1/2} A^{1/2} = A^{1/2} B^{1/2} $. That is not necessarily the case.

Comment: I don't think your solution works. According to your solution we have $A^{1/2} B A^{1/2} = (C^{1/2} B^{-1} C^{1/2})^{1/2} B (C^{1/2} B^{-1} C^{1/2})^{1/2}$, which is not equal to $C$ without some very special extra assumptions.

Comment: Seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the matrices are symmetric and positive definite, you shall be able and express
$B$ and $C$ as
$$
B = U\;\Sigma \;\overline U \quad C = V\;\Lambda \;\overline V  = V\;\left( {\Lambda \Sigma ^{\, - 1} } \right)^{\,1/2} \;\Sigma \;\overline {\left( {\Lambda \Sigma ^{\, - 1} } \right)^{\,1/2} } \;\overline V 
$$
where the overbar indicates the transpose, and $\Sigma, \;\Lambda$ are diagonal.

Thereupon you get
$$
\eqalign{
  & A^{\,1/2} \,U\;\Sigma \;\overline U \,A^{\,1/2}  = A^{\,1/2} \,U\;\Sigma \;\overline U \,\overline {A^{\,1/2} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {A^{\,1/2} \,U} \right)\;\Sigma \;\overline {\left( {A^{\,1/2} \,U} \right)}  = V\;\Lambda \;\overline V  =   \cr 
  &  = V\;\left( {\Lambda \Sigma ^{\, - 1} } \right)^{\,1/2} \;\Sigma \;\overline {\left( {\Lambda \Sigma ^{\, - 1} } \right)^{\,1/2} }  \cr} 
$$
i.e.:
$$
A^{\,1/2}  = V\;\left( {\Lambda \Sigma ^{\, - 1} } \right)^{\,1/2} U^{\, - 1} 
$$

But from here I don't see a way to express $A^{1/2}$ directly in function of $B$ and $C$.