# Quadratic matrix equation $XAX=B$

Tags: matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive semidefinite $n \times n$ matrices. Does the following quadratic matrix equation have a solution in the set of real symmetric matrices?

$$XAX=B$$

It's a special case of the Riccati equation. I want just to prove the existence of such real matrix $X$.

Comment: if you intend, as one of the tags, that $A,B$ are symmetric, and the rank of $A$ is at least as big as the rank of $B,$ then there really is a solution to $W^T A W = B.$

Comment: there seem to be a few things calle matrix Riccati...

Comment: @WillJagy can the matrix W be symmetric?

Comment: Obviously there is no solution if $\text{rank}(B) > \text{rank}(A)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140840/339790

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume $A$ is positive definite.  Multiplying on left and right by $A^{1/2}$ (the positive definite square root of $A$) the equation becomes
$$ (A^{1/2} X A^{1/2})^2 = A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$$
Now $A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$ is positive semidefinite, so has a positive semidefinite square root $C$, and we can take $X = A^{-1/2} C A^{-1/2}$ so that $C = A^{1/2} X A^{1/2}$.

Comment: well i think you reasoning is correct when A is positive definite but when its not if we take $X=A^{-1/2}(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}A^{-1/2}$ we get that $XAX=P_ABP_A$ where $P_A$ is the projector of Range(A) on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: If $A$ is not positive definite, what do you mean by $A^{-1/2}$?  Perhaps a pseudo-inverse?

Comment: yeah the pseudo inverse in the sense of moore-penrosae