# Showing a matrix identity

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric, positive definite matrices. Consider the following equations:
$$ B = XAX, \qquad A = YBY,$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are also symmetric and positive definite matrices.
These equations admit the solutions 
$$
\begin{aligned}
    X &= A^{-1/2}(A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})^{1/2} A^{-1/2}, \\
    Y &= B^{-1/2}(B^{1/2} A B^{1/2})^{1/2} B^{-1/2},
\end{aligned}
$$
see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326534/quadratic-matrix-equation-xax-b).
Given the reasoning in the linked post and the uniqueness of the matrix square root,
it should hold that **$Y$ is equal to $X^{-1}$**.
Is there a more direct way to see this, from the expressions of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: As evidence of this claim, I generated a bunch of PD matrices $A,B$ in Mathematica and confirmed that all such examples satisfied $XY=I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $C = B^{1/2} A^{1/2}$ and get its SVD:
$$
C = U S V^T
$$
Then we have
$$
A^{1/2} B A^{1/2} = C^T C = V S^2 V^T = ( V S V^T )^{2}
$$
and
$$
B^{1/2} A B^{1/2} = C C^T = U S^2 U^T = ( U S U^T )^{2}
$$
Next we write
$$
XY = A^{-1/2} (C^T C)^{1/2} C^{-1} (C C^T)^{1/2} B^{-1/2}
$$
or
$$
XY = A^{-1/2} ( V S V^T ) V S^{-1} U^T ( U S U^T ) B^{-1/2}
= A^{-1/2} V S U^T B^{-1/2}
= A^{-1/2} C^T B^{-1/2} = I
$$

Comment: Very nice, thanks!